# Auto close of html tags and jsp, php, asp tags in notepad++ and a semicolon at the end of the line written of scriptlets

Tags: php, html, notepad++

I use [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) and I like it

I specifically want it to do this :

1. Close automatically HTML tags. (eg. `</div>`)
2. Close tags after starting with proper indention for .jsp, .asp, .php files. (eg.`<%` `%>`, `<?php` `?>`)
3. Put a semicolon at the line end by default (whenever I start a new line inside `<?php ?>`)

For (1), it is really frustrating for me, when I want to write HTML tags in php files.
I upgraded to **6.5.1**, and tried the **TextFX**, but it works only with files which have the extension `.html` or `.htm`

Could someone please guide me in achieving these features?

Comment: I haven't used n++ in ages, but, i know for a fact that http://www.sublimetext.com/ has such a feature! for numberes amount of languages

Comment: are you sure this only works with .htm / .html files? Or has it to do twith the Language for syntax highlighting? (See menu Language in Notepad++)

Comment: If it works with .html and .html, than for other extensions change language to HTML `Menu/Language/H/HTML`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Regarding auto-closing html tags, for me only having html as the language didn't do the trick.

(This answer is incomplete, but is too large for a comment given the images.)

---

Changing the auto-complete preferences, as below, worked:

- **Settings** > **Preferences**

[image: settings_prefs]

- **Auto-Completion** tab > **Auto-Insert** section > **html/xml close tag**

[image: auto-insert]

I use Notepad++ v6.5.2

Comment: I would like to appreciate your support. But this solution will only work if the files are .html, .htm, .xml.                                                                                If i'm in .php this will not work anyomre.

Comment: I see, I didn't try it with php - only html. 
I was searching for the question regarding html (not php) and found that this added step was needed in my case, hence thought I'd post the answer in case of a similar situation  arises for others.
Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This answers at least part of the OP's question, the part about HTML. This is just what I've been looking for. I'm using version 6.5.5.

Comment: @RaviMca When you open a file with the `.htm` or the `.html` extension inside Notepad++ it automatically sets the language to HTML. If your file has a different extension, and you want Notepad++ to auto-insert HTML close tags, then you will have to change the language setting to HTML. At least temporarily while you work with HTML, then you can switch back to PHP or whatever your setting was. I just changed the extension of a file from `.htm` to `.php` and opened it in Notepad++ HTML tag close got broken. The moment I changed the language to HTML, tag close started working.

Comment: i didnt see that option dialog in notepad 6.3.3 ... where should i go then?

Comment: I was actually looking for something similar to ["Auto Rename Tag"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag) for VSCode - but for Notepad++. Alas, I have come to the conclusion that such a package does not seem to exist for Notepad++. Judging from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413686).

Answer (score 4):

If you are editing a PHP file and want it to auto-complete the HTML tags, in addition to turning on "Auto-insert HTML/XML tags" in Preferences, you have to change the programming language to HTML while editing that file.

In Notepad++, go to the **Language** menu, and find **HTML** and click on it.

This will set the file's language to HTML so that auto-complete tags will work in a PHP file.

Even with the language set to HTML, it still highlights anything in <?php ?> tags as PHP code, and it does not affect auto-closing of brackets, if you have that enabled.

You must have **Auto-Insert html/xml close tags** on, as mentioned in Noha's answer.

- Settings > Preferences
- Auto-Completion tab > Auto-Insert section > html/xml close tag

Answer (score 0):

For 2. you can't enter custom pairs for auto-complete (in the Auto-Insert section) with two characters. So this is not possible without a plugin. If I find one, I will update my answer.

3. However, for auto closing code with semicolon ";", you can use this option and "trick" Notepad++ to not put it on every line inside a php tag (which I don't believe is a good use case), but put it only when needed. I tested with ; and ; as opening and closing tags, which essentialy gives you what you need (without the php tags check though) and it's not so nice. But if you use an opening tag of "$" and a closing one ";", then you can get an auto-close functionality whenever you use a variable (which will mean you are writing code).

Please note that using < and > or any other similar pairs will break other auto-complete functionality (including the auto-close html tags). This is certainly bad, because it would be nice to have both <> auto close and html tags auto-close.