# How to change XHTML closing tags automatically in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I apologize if this has been asked before, but I don't believe it's been clearly asked, causing a lot of confusion on stackoverflow....I'm using Notepad v6.6.9 and I am looking for way to automaticlaly change my closing element tags when I want to "later" change my opening element tags. For example if I have an XHTML page with the following content....

```
<p>hello world</p>
```

...and I save this page, and re-open it, and then click to change `<p>` to `<h3>`, I want notepad++ to automatically change my closing `</p>` element to `</h3>`

Another way to put it:

"As I am typing and changing the currently selected opening tag, I want the closing tag to automatically change during the same time."

Is this possible in Notepad++? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto close of html tags and jsp, php, asp tags in notepad++ and a semicolon at the end of the line written of scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373962/auto-close-of-html-tags-and-jsp-php-asp-tags-in-notepad-and-a-semicolon-at-t)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood your question but I'll try to answer it.

you can replace all your inside tags with notepad++ using this way:

1. click on CTRL+F to open the find pop up.
2. navigate to replace tab
3. for your example, Replace only the P inside the tags to make it h3.
4. Click Replace All.

[image]

This will replace all the P into h3 and keep your starting / ending tags unharmed.

Hope that was helpful.

EDIT: Based on my comment, below is my trick:

1. go to settings menu
2. click on preferences
3. select Auto-completion
4. check the html/ xml close tags
   [image]

[image]

As I said, this will auto close the tags but I did not test it for auto changing closed tags.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  Not what I am looking for though...I currently do that.  As I am typing and changing the currently selected opening tag, I want the closing tag to automatically change during the same time.

Comment: in this case, I know a trick to auto-close html tags but I'm not sure if it will auto change the closing tags:

Comment: Thank you so much Riggs.  And your last statement is the thing I'm looking for - "automatically changing the closing tags" not just auto completing HTML element.