# Auto Completion Closing tags in html notepad++

Tags: html, autocomplete, notepad++

I have just started using notepad++. I wanted to know if there is a way to create a closing tag automatically in HTML, For example:
If I type:
     `<body>`
It will close the tag automatically:
    `</body>` 
I tried to adjust the Settings/Preferences/Auto-Completion, And I enabled the HTML/XML close tags, but that didn't work, Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of notepad++ are you using...it works for me.

Comment: I am using notpad++ v 6.6.9

Comment: Are you trying it in a file in which the Language is set to HTML?

Comment: Yes, It is set in default to html, and the other auto-completion works like {} [] etc, but it is just the tag auto-completion that doesn't work.

Comment: mine html autoclosing is fine. But if i saved the file .php so the html autoclosing doesnt work anymore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing that You looking for plugin TextFX Settings. To enable it go into menu:

```
 TextFX  -> TextFX Settings -> chek option 'auto close XHTML tags'
```

If You don't have installed this plugin, do this:

```
 Click Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager
 On the 'available' find and select 'TextFX Characters'
 Click Install and restart Notepad++
 Enable the 'auto close XHTM tags' as described above.
```

And do not forget to set the type of document to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done everything listed, and it still doesn't work. Try going to the "Language" (next to the settings part) and turn html on. This was the problem for me. Now it works fine for my with the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I remember (when I used windows machine), there was common problem with html tags.
Try to uncheck all checkboxes in Preferences when on the list (on the left side).
Next, hit close.
Then open it again and check only html/xml close tag checkbox.
In my case it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work :(, I can don't know why, but I tryed closing it and unticking all the boxes in Settings/Preferences/Auto-completion and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This question is exactly answered by Noha Kareem, here:
[Auto close of html tags and php tags in notepad++ and a semicolon at the end of php lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373962/auto-close-of-html-tags-and-php-tags-in-notepad-and-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of).
I hope this helps